# Can't figure out why nginx won't serve css, js, images files

Tags: javascript, css, nginx, jpeg

I've been trying to make this work for hours. I just get 404s This is what I currently have for my nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       127.0.0.1;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /laravel/public;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        #   root   /laravel/public;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
        #   root                     /laravel/public;
            fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass             127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index            index.php;
            fastcgi_param            SCRIPT_FILENAME  C:/nginx/laravel/public$fastcgi_script_name;
            include                  fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
        #   root   /laravel/public;
            try_files $uri =404;
        }
    }
}
```

I've checked the following and none of these paths work:

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/img/apple.png

http://localhost/public/img/apple.png

http://localhost/img/apple.png

http://localhost/apple.png
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't work. Some help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm using nginx version 1.10.2

EDIT: I get nothing in the error log and get the following in the access log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2016:19:54:44 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4482 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2016:19:54:44 -0800] "GET /css/raw.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "http://localhost" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2016:19:54:44 -0800] "GET /css/app.css HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "http://localhost" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2016:19:54:44 -0800] "GET /js/app.js HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "http://localhost" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2016:19:54:44 -0800] "GET /img/apple.png HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "http://localhost" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2016:19:54:44 -0800] "GET /js/app.js HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "http://localhost" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: have you checked your nginx access log and error log to see what's happening?

Comment: No errors in the error log. I updated the question with the access log.

Comment: so, where, on the server, relative to `index.php` are the css/js/image files - do the paths in the log look correct to you?

Comment: index.php is in the 'public' folder and the 'css', 'js' and 'img' folders are also in the 'public' folder. The paths in the log look like they should work.

Comment: what happens if you remove the whole `location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ {` block ... if you made changes, you do restart nginx I assume

Comment: I added that bit to try and make the files load. I tried removing it now and I get the same 404.

Comment: You use `C:/nginx/laravel/public` to access your PHP files and `/laravel/public` to access your static files. Should these both be the same path?